# Linux - I added conio.h header file to use the clrscr() function but whenever I call the function I receive this error

Tags: c, linux, gcc, gcc-warning

> #define clrscr ___CONIO_H.clrscr
> Expands to:  ___CONIO_H.clrscr
> identifier "___CONIO_H" is undefined

Comment: The `conio` library is a left-over from the old DOS days, and for some reason left in Windows. It's old and ancient and non-portable and not really a good thing to learn for the last 20 or so years. Where did you find a Linux implementation of it?

Comment: Oh... `conio.h` is an ancient DOS header, do not use it. Use `stdio.h` instead. Don't worry about `clrscr()` it isn't necessary to the logic of your code.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude  I found this at github https://github.com/zoelabbb/conio.h

Comment: sad thing is some educational institutions still use ancient compilers for teaching

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin  It's necessary and mandatory! to clear screen, how else can I do it on linux?

Comment: If it is mandatory for an assignment, then your other alternative is to use ANSI escape sequences. Just search "ANSI clear screen". I encourage you not to worry about reinventing a text *Interface* and instead focus on your *Implementation* (the logic of your code). If you really need all the bells and whistles of a text interface, then the ncurses library has all that for you. Understand that `clrscr()` doesn't really clear the screen -- it just outputs a screen worth of blank lines to scroll exiting text up.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin   Thanks

Comment: Try `printf("\033[2J");fflush(stdout);` - it is the ANSI escape sequence for clearing the screen.

Comment: @cup thanks, but what's the flushing for?

Comment: printf buffers the command.  flush flushes the buffer.  If you don't flush, it may or may not clear the screen immediately.  It might happen a lot later.